# How can I understand the sign of second derivative at the extrema?

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

Can someone explain why is the second derivative $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ of a function $y=f(x)$ at a minimum (maximum) is positive (negative)?

Can we arrive at any conclusion from the definition of the second derivative as the derivative of the first derivative, and using the definition of derivative?

Comment: It can also be zero. Consider $y=x^4$ at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x_0$ is a minimum of $f$, so that $f^\prime (x_0) = 0$.

Since $x_0$ is a minimum, $f$ must be increasing to the right of $x_0$. That is, $f^\prime$ must be positive in this neighbourhood. What does this imply about $f^{\prime \prime}(x_0)$?

Comment: What about the left of $x_0$?

Comment: The reasoning I give should easily extend to that case as well (along with the case of a maximum). Since $x_0$ is a minimum, $f$ must be decreasing to the left of $x_0$. In particular, $f^\prime$ must be negative just to the left.

Comment: $f$ is also increasing to the left of $x_0$ if it is a minimum.

Comment: No, if $f$ were increasing to the left of $x_0$, $x_0$ would not be a minimum. Note that “increasing to the left of $x_0$” does not mean the same thing as “increasing as you move left from $x_0$”. When we speak of functions and say they are increasing, we always mean movement from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

My intuition is the following: At a minimum, a function $f$ goes from being decreasing to being increasing. In other words, its derivative $f'$ goes from being negative to being positive. So $f'$ is then increasing, i.e. $f''$ is positive.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_0$ be the critical point, that is: 
$$f'(x_0)=\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=0.$$
The second derivative test: Assume $f''(x_0)>0$, then:
$$f''(x_0)=\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f'(x)-f'(x_0)}{x-x_0}=\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f'(x)-0}{x-x_0}>0.$$
Hence:

If $x\to x_0^-$ (i.e. $x$ approaches $x_0$ from the left side), then $x-x_0<0$ and $f'(x)<0$.

If $x\to x_0^+$ (i.e. $x$ approaches $x_0$ from the right side), then $x-x_0>0$ and $f'(x)>0$.

Hence, the function changes from a decrease ($f'(x)<0$) to an increase ($f'(x)>0$) over $x_0$, indicating the function achieves its local minimum at $x_0$.